# Code Igniter sessions are not setting when redirected

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am setting a session in login function
my controller is like

```
public function login() {
        if ($_POST) {
            $this->load->model('admin/loginmodel');
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            if ($username === "") {
                $data['username_error'] = 'User Name required';
            }
            if ($password === "") {
                $data['password_error'] = 'Password required';
            }
            if ($username === '' && $password === '') {
                $data['password_error'] = '';
                $data['username_error'] = '';
                $data['general_error'] = 'Please enter Username and Password to proceed';
            }
     if ($username !== '' && $password !== '') {
     $row = $this->loginmodel->verifyUser(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
                if ($row) {
                    $adminSessionData = "";
                    foreach ($row as $adminData) {
                        $adminSessionData['id'] = $adminData['pk_admin_user_id'];
                        $adminSessionData['username'] = $adminData['admin_username'];
                        $adminSessionData['status'] = $adminData['admin_user_status'];
                    }
                    $this->session->set_userdata('admin_data', $adminSessionData);
//                    echo "<pre>";
//                    print_r($this->session->userdata);
                    redirect(base_url('cpl_admin'));
                } else {
                    $data['general_error'] = 'Invalid Credentials';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $data['title'] = "My title";
            $this->load->view("admin/login", $data);
        }
    }
```

and my index function is

```
public function index() {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->session->userdata('admin_data'));
        echo "</pre>";
        if ($this->session->userdata('admin_data')) {


            echo "all is well";
        } else {
            $this->login();
        }
    }
```

It always redirects me to login function but after logging in, I can see the `Array` of my `user_data` items, but not in index function

**EDIT**

My output in index function is

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => 68bf28d789f90adb252e19c28f837a6a
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
    [last_activity] => 1430655856
)
```

Comment: 1) in the `index function` whats the output? Completely blank or an empty `Array()` or something else? 2) Consider writing `$this->session->all_userdata();` instead, what's the output?

Comment: In your `login` function, replace the current line with the following:
`$this->session->set_userdata('testing', 'works');` (for debugging purposes). Whats the output in `login` and `index`?

Comment: The out put is still same, it is not setting any session in index function

Comment: make sure session library is loaded in auto load or in the function or in the constructor of controller.

Comment: it is loaded in autoload and constructor as well

Comment: if its in autload.php than remove it from constructor and to set the session data of a table row use $this->session->set_userdata($adminSessionData);

Comment: well it worked, i  changed this line `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;` to `false`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 CI 2.xx session can be used without database.